# How do I set the default group for a vsftpd user's uploads? (ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, groups, vsftpd

How do I set the default group for a vsftpd user's uploads?

When I upload a file, the files group is set to the username... How do I get it to automatically set to a specific group?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easiest way to do it would be to set the directory's group to the group you want, and then set the sticky group bit on the directory with `chmod g+s`.

Comment: make sure that you do  it as sudo no errors are displayed if the command is run as non sudo.